# How to add styles in "print", and not remove the "screen" styles?

Tags: css

I guess it is very simple but for some reason I can't find the answer.

I wan't to create a "print" media section in CSS3, but I wan't only to add styles to the existing elements without removing all the "@media screen" styles.

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: How are you currently defining your screen styles? Can we see some code?

Comment: With "@media print" section in my main CSS file.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: Screen, not print. Is it with @media screen, <link media="screen">, or <link media="all">?

Comment: You should clarify, in the question itself, what you mean by “screen styles” and why you expect that “print style” could possibly remove them.

Answer (score 0):

What defined print styles if you want to make the printed default? Screen printed and you do not need to define print. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp But you can try this:

```
@media print and screen {

// your styles for screen and print

}
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen and print" />
```

Comment: "@media print and screen" is not working, but "@media screen, print" is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Is not logic want to set `print` definition if you want to print page with `screen` definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen, print {

//styles for screen and print

}
```